# How do I stop my if statement looping twice?

Tags: image-slider

I have an image slider, that has 6 full screen images, and it starts at 1 but then jumps to 3, then 5, then 1, then back to 3 then 5 etc. It seems like the part where checked is set to true in 'else' is being looped on itself twice.

This is the code as it is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
var TIMEOUT = 6000;

var interval = setInterval(handleNext, TIMEOUT);

function handleNext() {

  var $radios = $('input[class*="slide-radio"]');
  var $activeRadio = $('input[class*="slide-radio"]:checked');

  var currentIndex = $activeRadio.index();
  var radiosLength = $radios.length;

  $radios
    .attr('checked', false);

  if (currentIndex >= radiosLength - 1) {
    $radios
      .first()
      .attr('checked', true);
  } else {
      console.log("checking")
    $activeRadio
      .next('input[class*="slide-radio"]')
      .attr('checked', true);
  }
}
});
```

Here is a link to the page [my website](https://www.accend4web.co.uk/Noma/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasnt the function itself, but the actual js file being loaded twice, so I moved the jquery function into the ehad and problem solved.